Problem connecting Here3+ to orange cube+
I tried to follow the tutorial at http://www.worldronemarket.com/here-3-gps-manual/ and connected the red cables of the here3+ to the CAN1 of the cube board.
The next step would be to modify parameters like CAN_D1_PROTOCOL and GPS_TYPE, but they just do not exist/are not visible. Neither when I connect using Mission planner nor mavproxy. Other parameters are visible and modifiable.
And without changing the parameters, no data is published on the ROS GPS nodes.
What to do? How can i change these parameters when I don`t find them?
Do i need to change anz other parameters to enable the CAN parameters?
I use Linux on a Jetson Nano to connect to the cube. I think I'm using PX4 Autopilot fmu-v5.
I tried to connect both cables of the here3, or plug the red cable into CAN2.
I set UAVCAN_ENABLE to 3, no change. I dont have a sd card inserted, is this necessary for the dynamic node id?

This sounds like a question far more suitable for https://drones.stackexchange.com/. "Any issues regarding the software for a drone / model aircraft are on-topic. The question should include details of the software, including: the name of the software, what is the problem and what you have tried so far"
